# Compiler errors within my class

Tags: java

I was trying to create an uncrate simulator for TF2 crates, but I can't run it because of compiler errors. Errors indicated on code lines with comments.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String vitaSaw = "You got a Vita-Saw!";
        String gunSlinger = "You got a Gunslinger!"; 
        String equaLizer = "You got an Equalizer!";
        String scottishResistance = "You got a Scottish Resistance!";
        String oldGuad = "You got an Old Guadalajara!";
        String napperRes = "You got a Napper's Respite!";
        String nameTag = "You got a Name Tag!";
        String whitePaint = "You got An Extrodinary Abundance of Tinge!";
        String blackPaint = "You got a Distinctive Lack of Hue!";
        String unUsual = "****CONGRATULATIONS**** YOU JUST GOT AN UNUSUAL!";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char input;

        do {
            out.print("Uncrate? (y/n)");
            input =
            keyboard.findWithinHorizon("." ,0) .charAt(0); // Error 1
        } while (input = "y");  // Error 2

        int val = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;    

        if (val = 1) { // Error 3
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, unUsual);
            }
        }   

        if (val != 1 && val <= 11) {
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, vitaSaw);
            }
        }

        if (val > 11 && val <= 22) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, gunSlinger);
        }

        if (val > 22 && val <= 33) {
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, equaLizer);
            }
        }

        if (val > 33 && val <= 44) {
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, scottishResistance);
            }
        }

        if (val > 44 && val <= 55) {
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, oldGuad);
            }
        }

        if (val > 55 && val <= 66) {
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, napperRes);
            }
        }

        if (val > 66 && val <= 77) {
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, nameTag);
            }
        }

        if (val > 77 && val <= 88) {
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, whitePaint);
            }
        }

        if (val > 88 && val <= 99) {
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                (null, blackPaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error 1:

> The method findWithinHorion(String, int) is undefined for the type Scanner.

Error 2:

> Type mismatch error cannot convert from char to boolean

Error 3:

> Type mismatch error cannot convert from int to boolean

How do I fix these?

Comment: Maybe pasting the stacktrace is more helpful than describing the errors. :)

Comment: @Bonifacio2 these are compiler errors, not exceptions being thrown at runtime. There's no stacktrace to read.

Answer (score 2):

> Error 1: The method findWithinHorion(String, int) is undefined for the type Scanner.

This is noted in this line of code:

```
input = keyboard.findWithinHorizon("." ,0) .charAt(0);
```

You have declared a variable `Scanner keyboard`. **There is no method in [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)** class with the signature `findWithinHorion(String, int)`. This is a typo, you missed a `z`. The method you're looking is [`findWithinHorizon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findWithinHorizon-java.lang.String-int-):

```
input = keyboard.findWithinHorizon("." ,0) .charAt(0);
```

> Error 2: Type mismatch error cannot convert from char to boolean

Noted here:

```
} while (input = "y");
```

Input is `char`, a single `=` is variable assignment. You need to use equality comparator here: `==`. Also, double quotes is used for literal `String`s, change for single quote which is used for `char`.

```
} while (input == 'y');
```

> Error 3: Type mismatch error cannot convert from int to boolean

Noted here:

```
if (val = 1) {
```

Similar case to Error 2. Use `==` instead:

```
if (val == 1) {
```

Comment: Scanner class have this method with same signature.

Comment: @Panther it doesn't. I have checked that it's a typo :P

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html its there public String findWithinHorizon(String pattern,
                       int horizon)
Attempts to find the next occurrence of a pattern constructed from the specified string, ignoring delimiters.

Comment: @Panther again, **it was a typo**. Check the code from OP and my correction. Read my comment and my answer, geez...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: The odd thing is that there's no typo in the code itself. But maybe OP fixed it during copy/paste?

Comment: ok got it . may be someone editted in class code, there he wrote horizon but below its horion. So i got confused

Comment: i also got confused by seeing his code . That's way find reason for only 2 errors. anyways Good job keep it up

Comment: @t0mppa that seems to be the case.

Comment: I actually fixed this.

Comment: So, all these got fixed, but now it says my keyboard scanner never closes and when I run this it is correct and continuously asks "uncrate?" without moving to my while statement. What happened?

Comment: @SamMader probably you want/need to change from `input == 'y'` to `input != 'y'`.

Comment: Aaaargh but now it won't loop.

Comment: @SamMader initialize `input` with `'\0'` on declaration like this: `char input = '\0'; do { ...`.

Comment: To avoid an "extended discussion" I made a Git for us to work on it. Would you be able to do so? https://github.com/PythonicMaster/TF2-Uncrating/

Comment: @SamMader sorry, I won't access there.

Comment: Do you have a problem with it? Hm, well, here is the problem. It won't let a char store that because a char can only hold one letter right? Also, I don't know how to modify the...nevermind. I see my error. Alright it's good to go! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use == instead of = for error 2 and error 3. == is equality operator in java , while = is just assigning , compiler is taking those as string and int instead of boolean.

Answer (score 0):

for error 2 and error 3, it's as Panther says,for error 1,you missed z(though not missing in code),if you still encounter it,I don't know but maybe it's in your jdk version, try updating the jdk, I have version 8 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get the first error, but it basically says that it can't find the method findWithinHorizon(String, int). You can try this:

```
findWithinHorizon(Pattern.compile(".", 0))
```

The second error is because you have used the assignment operator (=). You have to use the equals method for the String class:

```
while (input.equals("y"));
```

The third error is the same as the second error. The solutuon here is to use the equals operator (==):

```
if (val == 1)
```

You have to use the equals method from the String class to check if two strings are equal because == only works for primitive data types.